# C++ insert X vector data to another vector

Tags: c++, vector

Im having a problem with copying data from one vector to another.
To better understand my pquestion, imagine i have a vectorA and a vectorB, same datatype.
vector A has nothing inside and has 5 size.

I want to put the first 5 bytes from vectorB into vectorA, but i dont know how.
Basicly, something like this:

```
vectorA.insert(vectorB.begin(),5,vectorB(5));
```

That doesnt work, but how can i do something like that?
Should i turn the vector in a array? Im really clueless on what to do since im new to working with vectors, so anny help/solution would be great.

Regardless, thanks!

Comment: "vector A has nothing inside and has 5 size." That seems self-contradictory.

Comment: @juanchopanza what i mean is, it has enought size to hold 5 bytes

Comment: That sounds like *capacity*, but bytes isn't a good metric unless you have a vector of bytes.

Answer (score 2):

You can fill up `a` with `b`'s data like so:

```
std::vector<char> a,b;
// fill up b
a.insert(a.begin(),b.begin(),b.end());

// or if only wanting a certain number of bytes:
size_t bytes = 5;
a.insert(a.begin(),b.begin(),b.begin() + 5);
```

Be careful to make sure that `b` has enough data to insert if you go with the second method. You can check with a conditional or like so:

```
a.insert(a.begin(),b.begin(),b.begin() + std::min(b.size(), 5));
```

See [`std::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert)'s fourth prototype.

Comment: what if vectorB has more then 5 bytes, and i only want the first 5?

Comment: ill accept your awnser in 11 minutes, but thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply using a `for loop`

```
int size=5;
for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
{
   vectorA.push_back(vectorB[i]);
}
```